# Find all distinct path possibilities from php array

Tags: php, arrays, decision-tree

I'm trying to get all possibilities from a decision tree in PHP, my input looks like this :

```
array(
    (int) 61 => array(
        (int) 257 => '62'
    ),
    (int) 62 => array(
        (int) 258 => '63',
        (int) 259 => '63',
        (int) 260 => '64',
        (int) 261 => null
    ),
    (int) 63 => array(
        (int) 262 => '65',
        (int) 263 => '65',
        (int) 264 => '66',
        (int) 265 => '69'
    ),
    (int) 64 => array(
        (int) 266 => '65',
        (int) 267 => '66',
        (int) 268 => '66',
        (int) 269 => null
    ),
...
```

If null value is hit, path is complete.

First level key is the scene id, second level are the choices id as key and the next scene id as value.

I can't figure out how to handle this problem, I tried a recursive function like this :

```
function myRecursive($dialogs) {

        foreach($dialogs as $i => $scene_to_go) {
            if(empty($scene_to_go)) {
                $index++;
            } else {
                $result[$index][] = $scene_to_go;
                myRecursive($scenesArray[$scene_to_go]);
            }

        }

}

myRecursive($scenesArray[61]);
```

But it only works for the first possibility, I think I'm close to the solution ?
Problem is the ending condition, and how to avoid duplicates.

Thank you very much for your help.

**EDIT :** Expected result array should look like :

```
[
[61, 62, 63, 65],
[61, 62, 64, 65],
...
]
```

Comment: What is the output you expect from **myRecursive($scenesArray[62]);**

Comment: No specific output, i just want to push the scene_id in a $result array, for my current possibilty

Comment: so you inserting 62, thats what ? the choice the user made ? Then you ned all possibile paths with all nodes for the user ? Or do you Need every id which Points to null which can be reached ?

Comment: 62 is the scene the user went through, i need to push all the scene_id for a path in a single row of my result array

Comment: I do not understand what the output you expected, so give us a sample of input and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
   public function getNextScenes($sceneId, &$nextDialogsArray) {
        global $array;
        foreach($array[$sceneId] as $dialogId => $nextSceneId) {
            $nextDialogsArray[$dialogId] = [];

            if (!empty($nextSceneId)) {
                $this->getNextScenes($nextSceneId, $nextDialogsArray[$dialogId]);
            }
        }
    }

    global $array;

    $array = [/**/]; // The input array you mentionned up there

    $finalArray = [];

    $this->getNextScenes(61, $finalArray);

?>
```

If you flatten the `$finalArray`, then, you got the unique possibilities in the array keys.